# How much memory needed for build docker v1.9.0

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, containers

I check out the docker source 1.9.0, and try to build on AWS EC2. But failed, and error out.

```
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/6l: running gcc failed: Cannot allocate memory
```

I follow the [Work with a development container](https://docs.docker.com/opensource/project/set-up-dev-env/). The EC2 is `1GB` memory. How much memory is required for build docker v1.9.0?

**[Update 2015-11-13]**

The same EC2 can succeed to build 1.8.3, so there is no error in  environment.
After I update the memory to `2GB`, I succeed to build the 1.9.0.

Answer (score 0):

More?

There's no current benchmarks on minimum requirements to compile docker. You are likely building it with a t2.micro or t2.small and the short answer is to bump that up to compile it temporarily.